# SARIMA vs deseasonalizing with ARIMA

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

I am trying to check what is the differnce between  modeling a time series with:

- SARIMA
- Deseasonalizing it first and then using ARIMA

Is there a preferable method over the other? If yes, why ?

Comment: Related question: [ARIMA vs SARIMA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413176/arima-vs-sarima).

Comment: Depends on the data generating process and on the method of seasonal adjustment (there are many). Some processes can be better approximated by SARIMA, other by other models of seasonality.

Comment: @RichardHardy: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, you are right. Posted.

Comment: Dear Mr. @RichardHardy, thank you for your answer, however I think it is missing some references, o rat least some examples to show that in which cases deseasonalization is prefered over SARIMA.

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the data generating process and on the method of seasonal adjustment ("deseasonalizing") of which there are many. Some processes can be better approximated by SARIMA, other by other models of seasonality. There is no method or model that is universally the best.